# Noun for the quality of being a “femme fatale”

Tags: single-word-requests, derivational-morphology

In referring to a particular *femme fatale,* I described her "femme fataleness."

That is "ungrammatical" (I believe) but got the point across.

Is there a correct term for this particular attribute? If so, what is it?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't want to use the usual nominalization; few women are likely to be charmed to be used as examples of _femme fatality_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Actually, my audience was a group of women, who applauded my comments (except the offender). It was a case of "all against one."

Comment: Or perhaps keep it (quasi-)French with _femme fatalisme_.

Comment: One of my favourite terms comes to mind: *"slightly unhinged"*, which has some overlap *femme fatale*.

Comment: Generally speaking, 'calamitous womanliness,' 'death-bringing matronliness' and 'doom-laden femininity' will also win few friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps "Her femme fatale quality?"  I can't think of a shorter way of saying this.

Comment: Not bad. An upvote. You (indirectly) suggested another one: "femme fatality."

Answer (score 2):

It's a French construction in which the noun is *femme* and *fatale* is an adjective; so strictly speaking the derivation should be applied to *femme*. Regrettably, however, French appears to have no derivative meaning the "quality of being a woman".

Applying a derivation after translation to *fatal woman* would give you *fatal womanhood*, which somehow lacks the necessary pizzaz.

I think your best bet is to regard *femme fatale* as an English fixed phrase whose final  {e} is merely an orthographic residue of its origin. That will give you your own tongue-in-cheek derivative ***femme fatality***. I really don't think it gets any better than that.

Comment: Actually I believe "femme fatality" came from me (see my comment to David Garner). John Lawler's comment was amended after the fact.

Comment: And I've only just realized you're OP. 'Doh! ... but I still think it's the best choice open to you.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not quite underlining some of the particular qualities of a femme fatale, the word ["allure"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/allure?s=t) can be used to refer to those qualities of a person that contribute to her "femme fataleness" as in:

"Her sensuous beauty coupled with a certain cunning were her allure"

*Noun*
4. fascination; charm; appeal.

Comment: _Seductiveness_ also. [beauty, seductiveness, independence, sterility and death... (femme fatale qualities listed in the book "Four French Symbolists"))